# Is it better to expand an existing REST Api url or make another one if i want to archive two diferent but similar functionalities?

Tags: api, rest, single-responsibility-principle

I'm going to explain my point with a real life scenario. I have a bunch of Notification items, and an API that returns all their fields in json. Let's say that the route for this api is /api/nots

Also you can specify the user id that you want to search to see if it haves any notification.

```
api/nots?id=1
```

All the notifications belong to a user or a group of users. So for example the json returned from the request above would be something like this:

```
{
"id": 1,
"name" : "Notification for John Doe",
"date": "1-1-2021"
"destinataries" : "johndoe@example.com",
"readed" : 1
}
```

The "readed" field is the one that bothers me, let's say this notifications will end up in a list on your phone, and in the notification will appear a green tick depending if the "readed" field is true.

All the notifications when are created have the readed field presetted to false, so i need an api to change that value to true. I have two ways of doing so but i don't know which is more efficient.

The first one is creating another route just to change the value, where you specify the id of the notification, for example:

```
api/update-nots?id=123
```

The other one is reusing the first api (api/nots) and making it perform two different things (searching nots by id and changing a notification readed value).

```
api/nots?set_readed=123
```

Which way is better?

Answer (score 1):

As you know, there are many ways to do all things, in my opinion it will the best option:

```
GET ...api/users/<user_n>/nots // Get all user nots
PUT ...api/nots/<not_n> // Update a specific not.
 payload = { readed: true }
```

Why? *In my opinion*, is more readable, because: `api/nots?id=1` actually you don't know if your request is about not number 1 or about an user or about a group (why not? :)).
So, keep readable you api, more semantic. With the example above, you can understand the methods and routes, get all user nots by id, and update one.
This way you will extend your basic behaviour with other actions like "remember me before", that maybe will be an update with some time mark to other time, or you can consume all nots with `/nots`, etc.